# Change Saturdays and Sundays to Fridays

Tags: python, pandas

My DataFrame:

```
          start_trade  week_day
0 2021-01-16 09:30:00  Saturday
1 2021-01-19 14:30:00   Tuesday
2 2021-01-25 22:00:00    Monday
3 2021-01-29 12:15:00    Friday
4 2021-01-31 12:35:00    Sunday
```

There are no trades on the exchange on Saturday and Sunday. Therefore, if my trading signal falls on the weekend, I want to open a trade on Friday 23:50.

Expexted output:

```
          start_trade  week_day
0 2021-01-15 23:50:00    Friday
1 2021-01-19 14:30:00   Tuesday
2 2021-01-25 22:00:00    Monday
3 2021-01-29 12:15:00    Friday
4 2021-01-29 23:50:00    Friday
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it playing with `to_timedelta` to change the date to the Friday of the week and then set the time with Timedelta. Do this only on the rows wanted with the mask

```
#for week ends dates
mask = df['start_trade'].dt.weekday.isin([5,6])

df.loc[mask, 'start_trade'] = (df['start_trade'].dt.normalize() # to get midnight
                               - pd.to_timedelta(df['start_trade'].dt.weekday-4, unit='D') # to get the friday date
                               + pd.Timedelta(hours=23, minutes=50)) # set 23:50 for time

df.loc[mask, 'week_day'] = 'Friday'
print(df)
          start_trade week_day
0 2021-01-15 23:50:00   Friday
1 2021-01-19 14:30:00  Tuesday
2 2021-01-25 22:00:00   Monday
3 2021-01-29 12:15:00   Friday
4 2021-01-29 23:50:00   Friday
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
weekend = df['week_day'].isin(['Saturday', 'Sunday'])
df.loc[weekend, 'week_day'] = 'Friday'
```

Comment: It must change start_trade column too, setting correct date and time 23:50:00

Answer (score 1):

Or `np.where` along with `str.contains`, and `|` operator:

```
df['week_day'] = np.where(df['week_day'].str.contains(r'Saturday|Sunday'),'Friday',df['week_day'])
```

Comment: Dear friend, thank you for your answer. But the most important thing is to set the correct time in column start_trade